# Export as nested lists instead of (sub)sections with org mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

If I export an org file, like

```
* Item
** Subitem
*** Subsubitem
```

and export it to latex it is converted to something like

```
[...]

\section{Item}
\label{sec:org1a2bb17}
\subsection{Subitem}
\label{sec:org7bddadf}
\subsubsection{Subsubitem}
\label{sec:org29ffdb2}
```

I.e. it translates it to sections and subsections. How can I configure org mode to convert it to nested lists (using itemize or enumerate), e.g. as:

```
[...]

\begin{itemize}
\item Item
\begin{itemize}
\item Subitem
\begin{itemize}
\item Subsubitem
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
#+OPTIONS: H:0
```

and see the `Export settings` section of the manual with `C-h i g(org)Export settings` which says

> ‘H’
>
> ```
> Set the number of headline levels for export
> (‘org-export-headline-levels’).  Below that level, headlines are
> treated differently.  In most back-ends, they become list items.
> ```

The default list export to LaTeX is using `itemize` environments. The option `num:t` changes that to `enumerate` environments:

```el
#+OPTIONS: H:0 num:t
```

Comment: Does this also work with nested `enumerate` instead of `itemize`?

Comment: Yes - see edited answer.